# Locating the source of `CGContextErase' is obsolete

Tags: osx-mavericks

Since upgrading to Maverics, I get the following error

```
<Error>: The function `CGContextErase' is obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a library it uses, is using this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system performance.
```

I don't explicitly call this, and only use 3 system frameworks (including Quartz) with no other library calls.

I do use a number of `Core Graphics` methods, some of which presumably are responsible

I would appreciate any help on tracking down the source of this error, and also whether it represents a real problem.

Surely this must be in some Apple code. Either the calling method should be obsolete, or Apple should fix it.

**EDIT**

I have since found other references to this issue, including the IDLE interpreter supplied by Apple and Python TKinter.

Comment: Why not [set a breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010433-CH2-SW1) on `CGContextErase` and see when it gets hit?

Comment: I did try setting breakpoint on CGContextErase, but this is called in NSApplicationMain.
A bit of further digging chowed this was called in instantiating a view in the nib.
This uses QuartzCore.
The preceding call was InkInitializeInstanceGraphics, but none of the functions is covered in the API documentation.